# REACT NATIVE - Anyone know how to use Streaming for the ChatGPT 3.5/4 API in React Native?

Tags: react-native, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Anyone know how to implement the streaming feature in the gpt-3.5-turbo Api? Here is my working code that releases the entire answer at once. Looking to do it via Client side only unless I absolutely have to set up a server.

```
    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
      {
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        messages: [
          {
            role: 'system',
            content: JSON.stringify(userProfile),
          },
          ...messages.map((msg) => ({
            role: msg.sender === 'ai' ? 'assistant' : 'user',
            content: msg.text,
          })),
          {
            role: 'user',
            content: newMessage.text,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization:
            (API KEY HERE),
        },
      },

    );
    setIsLoading(false); // hide the loading image

    const aiReply = response.data.choices[0].message.content.trim();
    setMessages((prevMessages) => [
      ...prevMessages,
      { sender: 'ai', text: aiReply },
    ]);

    setNewMessage({ ...newMessage, text: '' });
    flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
  };
```